# Should we use G1 GC under Java 8 or wait for Java 9?

Tags: java, java-8, garbage-collection

Is the G1 GC in Java 8 in general production level quality? Is the G1 implementation in the latest Java 8 service release (almost) identical to what is included in Java 9?

In other words:

- Is it a good idea to evaluate applications with G1 and switch to G1 under Java 8 now?
- Can we expect updates to the G1 in Java 8 patch releases, so it is on the same level as in Java 9 (when this is possible)?
- or is it better to wait for Java 9 since the behavior will be different?

Comment: Java 9 will simply make G1 the default garbage collection for the JVM.  Are you looking for a comparison of G1 and the current default garbage collector?  Also, there are probably some improvements that will come to G1 with Java 9, but it most likely won't matter which garbage collector you choose to use.

Comment: _Are you looking for a comparison of G1 and the current default garbage collector?_ No. The question is if we want to do a comparison should we use the Java 9 EA because things are dramatically different/better, or can we use the Java 8 G1 implementaton since its basically the same?

Comment: Why the downvote? If GC performance is irrelevant to you that's okay. But the question is for those where it is relevant.

Comment: It depends what's important to you; if you want higher throughput, then stick with ParallelGC, but if you want less latency, switch to G1.  https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2015/07/31/WhatIsTheFastestGarbageCollectorInJava8.html

Comment: Yes, but that't not the question. I'd like to know whether G1 is perfectly usable in Java 8 now and whether there will be differences to expect in Java 9.

Comment: If they shipped it with Java 8, then yes, it's perfectly usable.

Comment: G1 was shipped with Java 7, it's perfectly fine to use now.  And only the JVM developers know if the Java 9 version of G1 will be any better than it's current version.

Comment: Thanks @LouisWasserman!

Comment: @JacobG., yes, which makes the question worth asking :)

Comment: "Is it a good idea to evaluate applications with G1 and switch to G1 under Java 8 now?" - why do you need other people's opinions to evaluate something? you're in the best position to figure out whether it works for your application, just try it. we don't have access to your application.

Comment: @the8472 actually you have, since open source. https://github.com/cache2k/cache2k-benchmark see also: https://cruftex.net/2017/03/28/The-6-Memory-Metrics-You-Should-Track-in-Your-Java-Benchmarks.html "why do you need other people's opinions to evaluate something?" Because its working okay with CMS now and it makes no sense to try out G1 now, if it is different in Java 9

Comment: nothing stops you from testing with both java 8 and 9

Comment: downvoting because question scope is too broad for being on-topic on SO.

Comment: Based on this scary bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8148175 you shouldn't use G1 on Java 8... this is the reason ElasticSearch doesn't support G1GC on Java 8 although some users are running with it: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/where-can-i-find-info-on-the-status-of-g1gc-in-lucene-and-es/149526/7

Comment: @JohannesB If I correctly understood your first link, the issue was solved, so we're safe to run G1 on Java 8, right? I tested the failing code and worked for me.

Comment: @Dalton, thank you for pointing out that Java 8u40 and later contains patches that fix some corruption issue, according to: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_g1gc_check.html and a backport of the issue I mentioned before in the mean time has been fixed with Java 8u201, but it begs the question: Is it worth the risk to go where so few before you have gone?

Comment: @JohannesB It was really a question, not pointing out anything... your comment startled me because I have been using JDK 8 + G1GC in production for 4 years... I think I'm one of the few now haha